# Network Throughput Speed Test

Tags: java, javascript, performance, flash

I'm planning on building a network throughput speed test (speed test) that will eventually be embedded in a website for random people to test their internet connection speed. The test will not only test their speed, but also trigger a test on the server to test the server uplink speed at the same time (to display as a comparison at that moment in time).

I'm very comfortable in Java - but an applet seems to be a poor choice in 2013.

The client is specifying they would like it in either Java (and applet) or Flash (oh god... ). I have no Flash experience, but once you know to program, you know to program... so it would just require learning the Flash toolchain/processes and syntax (hoping this isn't too crazy).

However, I feel Flash is a poor choice as well (it's already being killed off by Adobe and it seems futile to invest so much effort to learn a platform that will go away (relatively) sometime in the near future).

As the domain expert, I am free to make recommendations based on what I feel is not only viable, but makes sense. Javascript comes to mind here, but I have little Javascript experience too (so in same boat of having to learn it). I think Javascript's barrier to entry is much lower though since it's all embedded in HTML pages and I know HTML fairly well.

Anyways, please make recommendations for such a project (platform-wise) and if possible point me in some direction of source code or examples of other speed tests that I can review and learn from (i tried searching but all i get back is functioning speed tests like speedtest.com etc, not source or theory, or design patters behind them).

Comment: May I ask why you want to develop/design your own speedtest.com?

Comment: So that it is infinitely customizable and can do more than just test an end-users connection to some remote server. I want to kick off other tasks and return more data to display (it's marketing material really)

Comment: ... or if you did, why you wouldn't just copy it.

Comment: So that I understand how it's working and can imrpove/alter what it does. Speedtest.com surely has a lot more going on than just the visible javascript or flash on their page, and that's the problem. I can't find examples or source for similar products so that I can learn from them and implement my own.

Comment: To do a throughput tests, you send it data as fast as possible and see how long it takes to download it (It can be full of zeros,, it doesn't have to be a file)  For latency, the best test is round trip. Send a packet and time how long it takes to get a reply.  The trick of this web site is that they have local servers all over the world which is not so easy to replace.

Comment: If you don't want to use a Java applet, perhaps it's time to look at Java FX which is much more flashy. ;) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey I was more steering away from the Applet due to recent security exploits and the added dependency (customer must have java enable in the browser for it to work)... I was not aware that Java FX could find it's way into the browser, but even still, it would be an Applet, no?

Comment: certainly straight-forward to do in Flash (and talk of its demise is premature, at least on desktop, but thats another story). If you are only interested in targeting desktop users, Flash will suit fine - but if you want to target mobile devices too, i guess JavaScript is the way to go

Comment: @SnakeDoc The security exploit is only a problem if you try use it. ;)   However, if you can do it in JavaScript, this is likely to be the most portable between devices I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Test network speed using PHP/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850881/test-network-speed-using-php-javascript?rq=1)
They didn't find a answer but there are some good suggestions. Just read it :)

Comment: interesting read -- although the overall summary I got from that thread was the methods mentioned would be innaccurate and data would vary depending on the browser, home system's response time, etc. too many factors. Of course some of these factors are OK since they effect regular internet connection speeds too, but I just want to avoid adding any additional bottlenecks that would skew results.