# Can you make your web app html5 run offline when not connected to wifi?

Tags: html, html5-apps

I have finished my first web app and I have it cache.manifest for off line mode. Problem is in my area I have not got 3G readily available and when I run my app it is dog slow. Is there a solution to tell your browser to run from cache when not connected to wifi ?

Thanks steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't detect the internet detection method directly, but you could try testing the connection speed and acting on the result of that?

Here is another answer that may help you with that: [How to detect internet speed in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)

Having said that though, I was under the impression that the application cache file would be used in either situation and any files cached would be loaded anyway. The only time it would attempt to download them would be if the application cache file was updated prompting a refresh of all the cached files themselves...