# How do I sent additional data to javascript's fetch() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fetch-api

I want to use `fetch()` to query an API endpoint which powers my search page. It returns a list of search results in JSON format.

I also want to pass to the API the current query submitted by the user. The old implementation used jquery and [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Looking at the docs for getJSON, it says that I can pass in a `data` variable:

```
data
Type: PlainObject or String
A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
```

[Looking at the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for fetch, I'm not sure how to pass in data as part of my request. So my question is, how do I pass in a string that will be sent to the server along with my request?

EDIT: I think I can append the query to the request URL, like "/search/?q=Something" and send that. Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: isn't fetch only build to fetch fixed informations? in the docs i can't find anything to send parameters with fetch. there is get post getJSON ajax and much more with parameters

Comment: What if you don't want the data to be in the request - merely if you want to have the variable exist when responding to the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [Body section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body) of the documentation on fetch, it lists several types of values you can use to specify the data sent in your request.

Example using `FormData`:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('q', 'Something');

fetch('/search', {
  method : "POST",
  body : fd
})
.then(...)
```

Note that you can't use the `body` option on GET or HEAD requests (which it seems you may be doing in your case). In that situation, you can build up the parameters using `URLSearchParams`:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('q', 'Something');

fetch('/search/?' + params.toString(), {
    method: 'GET'
})
.then(...);
```

Comment: Plain `javascript` object does not appear to be tested or expected at `body` https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/blob/master/fetch/api/request/request-idl.html,  https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/blob/master/fetch/api/basic/request-upload.js

Comment: @guest271314 If I call `fetch('/save', {
 method : "POST",
 body : { data : 5 }
})` in my Chrome console, the request is sent with an empty body and `Content-Length` 0.

Comment: Yes, `javascript` object should be passed to `JSON.stringify()`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939857/fetch-with-readablestream

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as below

```
 fetch('/users', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: 'Hubot',
    login: 'hubot',
  })
})
```