# How do I send PHP POST and FILES data to an AJAX URL call when they are not from an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a PHP page with `$_POST` and `$_FILES` data filled in. The POST data was obtained **not** from a traditional HTML form, but between multiple pages.

For example, the POST data is a number of things:

```
$_POST["username"]
$_POST["password"]
$_FILES
etc.
```

The question is, how do I send this POST data off to an AJAX call within the page?

I know with a form it's something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'post.php',
   data: $('form').serialize(),
   success: function () {
     alert('form was submitted');
   }
 });
```

But what about directly from PHP's POST data?

Comment: Are you trying to send `$_POST` data from `php` to client?

Comment: I'm confused on what you're trying to do. 
AJAX is a client side concept of calling server side. Not the other way around. You cannot use Ajax server side in PHP code.

Comment: You want to return data to JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have slightly edited the post. The POST data is passed to second PHP page that loads and will have a realtime progress bar start automatically via Ajax calls. I can tell from the comments that I may have designed this incorrectly.

Comment: Do this: `data: { userid: "joe smoe", firstName:"joe"}` you can pass your values as parameters key: value...

Comment: They will be HTTP form params on the php side...

Comment: @brso05 I get that, but what about `$_FILES`?

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, how do I send this POST data off to an AJAX call
>   within the page?

You can use `WebSocket` or `EventSource` and possibly `ServiceWorker` to stream data from server to client. For example, see [How to read and echo file size of uploaded file being written at server in real time without blocking at both server and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475492/how-to-read-and-echo-file-size-of-uploaded-file-being-written-at-server-in-real) where the requirement is to stream the progress of bytes of uploaded file being written to file at server by `php` in real time without blocking.