# fetch POST is returning HTTP 415, while curl goes on fine and returns result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, fetch-api

This is what my code looks like

```
let body = {
            authCode: "XXXX",
            clientId: "YYYYYY",
            clientSecret: "ZZZZZZ"
        };


        fetch('https://api.myapp.com/oauth/token',{
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            mode: 'no-cors',
            body: body
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log("response: ", response);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("could not get tokens: ", error);
        })
```

In Chrome, this is what I see
[image]

I tried to do this by `curl command` and this is what it looks like

```
➜  ~ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "authCode": "XXXX",
  "clientId": "YYYYY",
  "clientSecret": "ZZZZZZZZ"
}' https://api.myapp.com/oauth/token
{"authToken":"e141kjhkwr3432ca9b3d2128385ad91db4cd2:cca6b151-cab4-4de2-81db-9a739a62ae88:23000000"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

After changing it to following, the result is still `HTTP 415`

```
fetch('https://api.myapp.com/oauth/token',{
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            mode: 'no-cors',
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log("response: ", response);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("could not get tokens: ", error);
        })
```

Interestingly, I realized that I sent the header `"Content-Type": "application/json"` while what I get back is `content-type: text/plain`, why that might be happening?

[image]

Comment: do you understand what `mode: 'no-cors'` does? Not saying that's your problem (the problem is most likely with the server side, I mean, why is it responding with 415, client side code can't really help with figuring that out) - but `mode: no-cors` will mean your code will always fail to access the response

Comment: JSON.stringify(body) ?

Comment: further to @karthick comment - `body: Any body that you want to add to your request: this can be a Blob, BufferSource, FormData, URLSearchParams, or USVString object.` - an object is none of these

Comment: Thanks, see my update

Answer (score 6):

you must define `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers like that and stringify your data object

```
const params = {
            headers: {
                'Accept': "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                'Content-Type': "application/json;charset=utf-8"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(yourObject),
            method: "POST"
        };

fetch(url, params)
        .then(data => { console.log('data', data)})
        .then(res => { console.log('res', res) })
        .catch(error => { console.log('error', error) });
```

Comment: why it is required as a must?

Answer (score 2):

`fetch()` does not expect a JavaScript object at `body`. `curl` command and `fetch()` pattern are not the same. Use `body: JSON.stringify(<javascript plain object>)`.

[`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request)

> Note: The `body` type can only be a `Blob`, `BufferSource`, `FormData`,
>   `URLSearchParams`, `USVString` or `ReadableStream` type, so for adding
>   a `JSON` object to the payload you need to stringify that object.

See [Fetch with ReadableStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939857/fetch-with-readablestream) for status of implementation of `ReadableStream` set as value for `body`.

Comment: Thanks, see my update. The response is still the same

Comment: @daydreamer Why do you set `headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            mode: 'no-cors'` headers? What is expected response?

Comment: expected response js in `JSON`. 'no-cors' since preflight requests fail otherwise

Comment: @daydreamer Response does not have CORS headers set. Why do you expect a `JSON` response?

Comment: The `fetch()` fails if I do not have `no-cors` set.

Comment: `Fetch API cannot load https://api.myapp.com/oauth/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 415. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: Well, it's not, but the question is that while tools like postman/curl do not have issues, browsers seem more strict about this

Comment: @daydreamer _"Well, it's not, but the question is that while tools like postman/curl do not have issues, browsers seem more strict about this"_  That is not the present Question. The original question does not mention postman or `curl`.

Comment: I agree with what you said. Thanks