# Error 415 when call POST API using Fetch in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I want to call an API for register from method in React. Below is my javascript code :

```
     fetch('http://localhost:5001/api/Account', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: "hugh.daniel@gmail.com",
            name: "Hugh Daniel",
            password: "1234"
        })
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

And this is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ResponseModel RegisterByEmail([FromBody]UserModel user)
    {
        return _accountService.RegisterEmail(user);
    }
```

But I always get these errors
[image]

I tried to add `mode: 'no-cors'` in my javascript code, but it makes `Content-Type` set to plain.
The API is working if I tested it using Postman like this
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to enable CORS on your controller ? Can try with any origin to start with, and then define your origin properly : [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]

Comment: @zer0chain I have tried it. It caused another error 500. It also happen in Postman, it returned error 500

Comment: Why do you `POST` to `"http://localhost:5001/api/Account"` from `"http://localhost:3030"`? Can you include actual text of error messages at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I created a front end for my apps using React in `"http://localhost:3030"`. And call REST API (created using .Net) in `"http://localhost:5001/api/Account"`

Comment: The error message appears to be clear, the request is cross origin and the server does not respond with CORS headers.

Comment: @Intan what is the content of the 500 you got ? Obviously the preflight failed because cors is not set properly on server, so you can to configure it or to disable it.

Comment: The cause of the problem you’re seeing is, the server for that `http://localhost:5001/api/Account` endpoint you’re making the request to is responding to an `OPTIONS` request with a `415 Unsupported Media` HTTP status code. It makes zero sense for a server to do that, & it pretty much indicates the server’s broken. Because the thing is, the `OPTIONS` request it’s responding to that way is a CORS preflight request your browser automatically on its own is sending to the server. And the browser doesn’t include any Content-Type header in that `OPTIONS` request. So the request has no media type.

Comment: To be clear: a properly-configured server should never be looking for a media type in an `OPTIONS` request; the server shouldn’t care if the `OPTIONS` request has no a Content-Type header, but it also shouldn’t care if it does have one. That’s because `OPTIONS` requests have no payload (request body) — just like `HEAD` requests have no payload. So the server doesn’t need a Content-Type in the request in order to respond to it; the request Content-Type is completely irrelevant for `OPTIONS`, so a server should never be responding to an `OPTIONS` request with a 415

Comment: i just add answer here see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192731/fetch-post-is-returning-http-415-while-curl-goes-on-fine-and-returns-result/62728896#62728896)

Comment: i just answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192731/fetch-post-is-returning-http-415-while-curl-goes-on-fine-and-returns-result/62728896#62728896)

Answer (score 4):

You need to combat CORS first of all. You can't make API requests against a different `domain:port` than the one from which it was served by development server. Are you using Webpack in your project? If yes, the easiest way is to set up API proxy by the Webpack configuration. [See the doc](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy). Something like this:

```
// webpack.config.js
devServer: {
    port: 3030,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: `http://localhost:5001`,
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
```

Now you have to remove `host:port` from `fetch` address param and also I would add `Accept` header to the request settings:

```
fetch('/api/Account', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    // ...
  }
)
```

Comment: Yes, the error about CORS is disappeared. But I still got error 415

Comment: @Intan Try to add Accept header. I've updated the answer.

Comment: still got the same error after I added Accept header

Comment: @Intan So it's definitely server side issue. Please update your post to provide request/response headers details, like a https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/imgs/headers.svg . And also give us please actual browser console log after the CORS is gone (is it gone?)

Comment: @Intan I made another one update to clarify the fetch request url param. After you set up proxy for dev server (if you really did it), you need to make api requests from the same `host:post` as the dev server (3030). In that case you may (even should) not to specify `host:port` in the address param, just `fetch('/api/Account/'...`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[ApiController]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("[controller]")]        
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{}
```

In js:

```
await fetch(this.url, { method: 'POST', cache: 'no-cache', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify(data) });
```

Sourse: https://pretagteam.com/question/angular-http-post-formdata-unsupported-media-type-from-c-controller

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `JSON.stringify` in the body for sending a request and following code will do the work.

```
fetch('http://localhost:5001/api/Account', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: {
        email: "hugh.daniel@gmail.com",
        name: "Hugh Daniel",
        password: "1234"
    }
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Removing `JSON.stringify` doesn't automatically convert the object to string. The invalid text `[Object object` will be passed instead.