# Request.body is empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, fetch-api

From my client-side I'm doing a fetch with data like this to a webhook on my Firebase node.js server.

```
const url = 'https://us-central1-<app>.cloudfunctions.net/addUserdata';
const data = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  email: 'john.doe@email.com'
}

const request = new Request(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: new Headers()
});

fetch(request)
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

I'm just trying to catch the data for now like this.

```
exports.addUserdata = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(200);
});
```

Unfortunately my req.body is an empty object. What I'm a missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `JSON`, `FormData`, `Blob` object or string to `body`. `Request.body` does not expect a JavaScript object.

```
body: JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: @Thore See [`Request()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) at _"Note: The body type can only be a `Blob`, `BufferSource`, `FormData`, `URLSearchParams`, `USVString` or `ReadableStream` type, so for adding a `JSON` object to the payload you need to stringify that object."_, see also [Fetch with ReadableStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40939857/)

Answer (score 0):

On `POST` requests you have to wait a bit to get data into `request.body`

```
    var body = '';
    req.on('data',function(data) { body += data; });
    req.on('end', function(data) {
        req.body = JSON.parse(body);
    });
```

Comment: Still getting an empty object