# How to get File upload progress with fetch() and WhatWG streams

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, whatwg-streams-api

*Note: I'm not looking for any alternatives. I know this can be done with XMLHttpRequest. I also don't care about browser support. I just want learn about the new/upcoming standards.*

I have a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object and I can upload it with PUT using fetch like this:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "PUT",
    body: fileObject,
});
```

How can I get upload progress from this?

From what I understand the `body` of the fetch options can be a [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream). So maybe there is a way to wrap the File object to a ReadableStream and get progress status from that?

Eg. something like this

```
fetch(url, {
    method: "PUT",
    body: asReadableStream(fileObject, onProgress),
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch with ReadableStream as Request Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939857/fetch-with-readablestream-as-request-body)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload progress indicators for fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711724/upload-progress-indicators-for-fetch)

Comment: Also see [whatwg/fetch/issues/607](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/607) (as mentioned in Mozilla's [example uploading a user-selected file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications#example_uploading_a_user-selected_file))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update

Chrome started to support streaming uploads https://chromestatus.com/features/5274139738767360

Here is a demo using a pull stream that the request calls when it's ready to accept more data for uploading

```js
let uploaded = 0
let buf = new Uint8Array(1024 * 50)
let start = Date.now()

var rs = new ReadableStream({
  pull(ctrl) {
    uploaded += buf.byteLength
    console.log('uploaded', uploaded)
    crypto.getRandomValues(buf)
    ctrl.enqueue(buf)
    if ((start + 1000) < Date.now()) ctrl.close()
  }
})

fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: rs,
  duplex: 'half'
}).then(r => r.json()).then(console.log)
```

<s>As Kyle said, ReadableStream uploading is not supported yet. https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/95</s>

Even if it is possible I would not try to monitor the upload progress throught streams, (that is if [FetchObserver](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/607) becomes a thing) Nobody is working on it right now. But Mozilla made a proposal that looks something like this.

```
/*
enum FetchState {
  // Pending states
  "requesting", "responding",

  // Final states
  "aborted", "errored", "complete"
};
*/

fetch(url, {
  observe(observer) { 
    observer.onresponseprogress = e => console.log(e);
    observer.onrequestprogress = e => console.log(e);
    observer.onstatechange = n => console.log(observer.state)
  }
)
```

I remember that i tested it using some experimental flags a long time ago but can't find the demo anymore, guess they removed it from MDN since it was there own implementation/suggestion.

enqueue bytes to a readable or a identity stream don't mean that you have uploaded the data to the server, it only signals that the request asking for more data to potentially fill up a bucket

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: cannot be done right now.

Checkout the spec here: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api

Second sentence indicates that there isn't a way to track *request* progression when using fetch.

> The fetch() method is relatively low-level API for fetching resources.
>   It covers slightly more ground than XMLHttpRequest, although it is
>   currently lacking when it comes to request progression (not response
>   progression).