# Upload files with fetch api & get file uploading data

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm using `XMLHttpRequest` to upload .psd files in my application & listening to events with `addEventListener`.

Code sample:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', url);
request.upload.addEventListener('progress', ({ lengthComputable, loaded, total }) => {
  if (lengthComputable) {
    const feedData = { loaded, total };
    // do something with the data
  }
});
```

How can I use `fetch` in place of `XMLHttpRequest` & access the `lengthComputable`, `loaded` & `total`?

Because I want to show a loading bar indicating the uploading progress with that data.

Comment: So you want a progress bar for the upload? If so then I have submitted a answer for this [**My Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674575/php-upload-extract-and-progressbar/26679480#26679480) I think the `addEventListener()` you want to set is `progress` for your `request`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422662/how-to-get-file-upload-progress-with-fetch-and-whatwg-streams asks basically the same question but also hasn’t received any answers yet. The gist of it is that for uploads with the fetch API, browsers unfortunately don’t yet support any way to expose the progress information you’d need. So I guess this is one of the few cases where you’d might want to still use XHR instead of the fetch API