# Is there a way to record sound and stream it in real time to a server using fetch () in React Native?

Tags: react-native, fetch, audio-streaming

Trying to record a file and as it is being recorded I want to post it to a server using fetch(). Is there a library that records sound and that pipes it continously to a file (or api)?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking several questions at once.  Let's break it into pieces.

## How can I capture sound?

I assume you want to record sound from a microphone or other audio input device.  To do that, you need to capture it with the MediaDevices API.  Specifically, you want to call `getUserMedia()` to get a MediaStream instance from a particular recording device.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

## How can I record a MediaStream?

You can use the MediaRecorder to take a MediaStream, run it through a codec, mux it into a particular format, such as WebM, and output a Blob.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder

## How can I get MediaStream data as it's being recorded?

When you call `mediaRecorder.start()`, be sure to call it with the timeslice parameter.  Something like `mediaRecorder.start(3000)` will cause it to emit a `dataavailable` event roughly every 3 seconds.  You can then take this data and ship it off to wherever.

## How do I make an HTTP request with a streaming request body?

You can't.  At least, not today.  See also:  [Fetch with ReadableStream as Request Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939857/fetch-with-readablestream-as-request-body)

What you *can* do is send data via Web Sockets.  You can also make HTTP requests for each chunk.

Comment: Did you mean `mediaRecorder.start()` or really `mediaStream.start()`?

Comment: @xybrek mediaRecorder, thanks for catching that!  Fixed.