# Stream request body with JavaScript's fetch API?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Is it possible to *send* a stream using the JavaScript `fetch` API?

For example:

```js
const stream = new ReadableStream(…) // for example, as returned by `File.stream()`
fetch('https://example.com/do-upload', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: stream,
})
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939857/fetch-with-readablestream-as-request-body?answertab=active#tab-top