# Polyfill for upload progress of fetch, without stream

Tags: file-upload, fetch

I ran into the problem of Fetch API does not support progress. I've read through the related [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711724/upload-progress-indicators-for-fetch) and ReadableStreams looks like a good candidate, however we cannot use it due to our dependency policy (still an early stage and has to be polyfilled in many [browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=ReadableStream)).

So we needed a polyfill built on recently available APIs, most likely XHR. I though I would share our implementation. It is not very complex though, but might save some time for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's our solution which falls back to XHR, while trying to stay close to fetch's signature. Note, that this focuses on the progress, response status and response data are omitted.

```js
interface OnProgress {
    (loaded: number, total: number, done: boolean): void;
}

export function fetch(url: string, { method, headers, body }, onProgress: OnProgress): Promise {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', e => onProgress(e.loaded, e.total, false));
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('loadend', _ => onProgress(undefined, undefined, true));
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4)
                resolve();
        };
        xhr.onerror = err => reject(err);
        Object.entries(headers).forEach(([name, value]) => xhr.setRequestHeader(name, value));
        xhr.send(body);
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```js
import { fetch } from 'my-fetch-progress';

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, file.name);
const onProgress = (loaded, total, done) => console.log('onProgress', loaded, total, done);

fetch('/my-upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ...` },
    body: formData
}, onProgress)
    .then(_ => /*...*/);
```