# Read a stream with for-await using JavaScript in the browser

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to download something large upon user gesture in the browser using `fetch` with progress indication:

```js
const url = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random';
const response = await fetch(url);
const total = Number(response.headers.get('content-length'));
let loaded = 0;
const reader = response.body.getReader();
let result;
while (!(result = await reader.read()).done) {
  loaded += result.value.length;
  // Display loaded/total in the UI
}
```

I saw a snippet in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47759960/2715716) which lead me to believe this could be simplified into:

```js
const url = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random';
const response = await fetch(url);
const total = Number(response.headers.get('content-length'));
let loaded = 0;
for await (const result of response.body.getReader()) {
  loaded += result.value.length;
  // Display loaded/total in the UI
}
```

`getReader` returns a `ReadableStreamDefaultReader` which comes from the [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) which is a web API as well as a Node API which makes finding only web related information really hard.

In the snippet above the code fails with *response.body.getReader(...) is not a function or its return value is not async iterable*. I checked the object prototype and indeed I don't think  it has `Symbol.asyncIterator` on it so yeah no wonder the browser failed to iterate over it.

So the code in that question must have been wrong, but now I wonder, *is* there a way to take a stream like this and iterate over it using `for-await`? I suppose you need wrap it in an async generator and yield the chunks in a similar way to the first snippet, right?

Is there an existing or planned API which makes this more streamlined, something closer to the second snippet, but actually working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ReadableStream itself [implements an async iterable](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#rs-asynciterator)

```
 for await (const result of response.body) {
   loaded += result.value.length;
   // Display loaded/total in the UI
 }
```

Comment: Can you turn the code block in your answer into a runnable snippet? I tried it and have not had success with it: https://jsfiddle.net/y9f2cpro/

Comment: Well, seems to be very new (April, this year), probably not supported yet.

Comment: I see that Microsoft Edge does not define a `Symbol.asyncIterator` on `ReadableStream`, meaning it doesn't allow `for await` to be used on readable streams. Yet. I assume same goes for Chromium.

Answer (score 3):

The `response.body.getReader() .read()` returns `{value:..., done: Boolean}` meets exactly what `asyncIterator` needs; before the ReadableStream itself got `asyncIterator` implementation, you can easily polyfill it:

```
if (!response.body[Symbol.asyncIterator]) {
  response.body[Symbol.asyncIterator] = () => {
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    return {
      next: () => reader.read(),
    };
  };
}
for await (const result of response.body) {
  loaded += result.length;
  console.log(((loaded / total) * 100).toFixed(2), '%');
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/6ostwkr2/

Comment: To add two thoughts to this, (1) we should probably add a "return" method to the iterator that calls `reader.releaseLock()` and (2) it's worth noting that this can be added to the prototype of ReadableStream making this available globally. Example: https://gist.github.com/sstur/29d7de58d3c7073781e26b46ee397dac