# How to track upload progress to S3 using aws-sdk V3 for browser (javascript)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I can find a lot of resources online on how to track upload progress to S3 using aws-sdk V2, listening to the event like:

```
.on('httpUploadProgress', event => {}
```

But since I updated the aws-sdk to V3, there are no listeners anymore. I believe I have to use the middleware function now, but I've tried a few things and it didn't work. I've also went deep into the [API reference docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/index.html) and the [github repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3) without success.

My current code is like this:

```
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

export const UploadToS3 = (credentials, fileData) => {

    const s3 = new S3Client({
        region: credentials.region,
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: credentials.access_key,
            secretAccessKey: credentials.secret_key,
            sessionToken: credentials.session_token,
        }
    });

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        s3.send(new PutObjectCommand({
            Bucket: credentials.bucket,
            Key: credentials.file,
            Body: fileData,
        }));
    });
};
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You might want to ask by raising an issue at the GitHib repo.

Comment: Great idea, thanks!

Comment: read this blog its include code link also https://www.internetkatta.com/develop-progress-bar-for-aws-s3-file-upload-using-javascript for creating progress bar

Comment: Thank you for the answer @aviboy2006, but this is an V2 example, using the event `httpUploadProgress` which is not available in V3 anymore

Comment: Let me try this. You are right. @yaiks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem (switched from aws-sdk v2 to v3) and found out that it is because the library uses the [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API for all HTTP Requests and `Fetch` [does not (yet) support tracking upload progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711724/upload-progress-indicators-for-fetch)

To solve that problem I exchanged `Fetch` by good old `XMLHttpRequest` at least for `PUT` requests, which you can accomplish by providing a custom **requestHandler** when initializing the S3Client.

```
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const myHttpHandler = new MyHttpHandler();
myHttpHandler.onProgress$.subscribe(progress => {
  const percentComplete = progress.progressEvent.loaded / progress.progressEvent.total * 100;
  console.log('upload progress', percentComplete);
});

const myClient = new S3Client({
  endpoint: this.configService.s3Api,
  region: 'eu',
  credentials: { ... },
  requestHandler: myHttpHandler
});
```

The custom request handler simply extends the `FetchHttpHandler` from @aws-sdk/fetch-http-handler. If the method is `PUT` and there is a body (so we want to upload something), it uses a custom XHR handler - otherwise it just uses the `Fetch` handler from it's `super` class.
And in the XHR handler you can bind something to the `progress` event of the XHR handler - in my case I emit a rxjs `Subject` which I can consume outside the custom handler.

```
import { FetchHttpHandler, FetchHttpHandlerOptions } from '@aws-sdk/fetch-http-handler';
import { HeaderBag, HttpHandlerOptions } from '@aws-sdk/types';
import { buildQueryString } from '@aws-sdk/querystring-builder';
import { HttpResponse, HttpRequest } from '@aws-sdk/protocol-http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

class MyHttpHandler extends FetchHttpHandler {
  private myRequestTimeout;

  onProgress$: Subject<{ path: string, progressEvent: ProgressEvent }> = new Subject();

  constructor({ requestTimeout }: FetchHttpHandlerOptions = {}) {
    super({ requestTimeout });
    this.myRequestTimeout = requestTimeout;
  }

  handle(request: HttpRequest, { abortSignal }: HttpHandlerOptions = {}): Promise<{ response: HttpResponse }> {
    // we let XHR only handle PUT requests with body (as we want to have progress events here), the rest by fetch
    if (request.method === 'PUT' && request.body) {
      return this.handleByXhr(request, { abortSignal });
    }
    return super.handle(request, { abortSignal });
  }

  /**
   * handles a request by XHR instead of fetch
   * this is a copy the `handle` method of the `FetchHttpHandler` class of @aws-sdk/fetch-http-handler
   * replacing the `Fetch`part with XHR
   */
  private handleByXhr(request: HttpRequest, { abortSignal }: HttpHandlerOptions = {}): Promise<{ response: HttpResponse}> {
    const requestTimeoutInMs = this.myRequestTimeout;

    // if the request was already aborted, prevent doing extra work
    if (abortSignal?.aborted) {
      const abortError = new Error('Request aborted');
      abortError.name = 'AbortError';
      return Promise.reject(abortError);
    }

    let path = request.path;
    if (request.query) {
      const queryString = buildQueryString(request.query);
      if (queryString) {
        path += `?${queryString}`;
      }
    }

    const { port, method } = request;
    const url = `${request.protocol}//${request.hostname}${port ? `:${port}` : ''}${path}`;
    // Request constructor doesn't allow GET/HEAD request with body
    // ref: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/551
    const body = method === 'GET' || method === 'HEAD' ? undefined : request.body;
    const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
      body,
      headers: new Headers(request.headers),
      method,
    };


    const myXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const xhrPromise = new Promise<{headers: string[], body: Blob, status: number}>((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        myXHR.responseType = 'blob';

        // bind the events
        myXHR.onload = progressEvent => {
          resolve({
            body: myXHR.response,
            headers: myXHR.getAllResponseHeaders().split('\n'),
            status: myXHR.status
          });
        };
        myXHR.onerror = progressEvent => reject(new Error(myXHR.responseText));
        myXHR.onabort = progressEvent => {
          const abortError = new Error('Request aborted');
          abortError.name = 'AbortError';
          reject(abortError);
        };

        // progress event musst be bound to the `upload` property
        if (myXHR.upload) {
          myXHR.upload.onprogress = progressEvent => this.onProgress$.next({ path, progressEvent });
        }


        myXHR.open(requestOptions.method, url);
        // append headers
        if (requestOptions.headers) {
          (requestOptions.headers as Headers).forEach((headerVal, headerKey, headers) => {
            if (['host', 'content-length'].indexOf(headerKey.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
              // avoid "refused to set unsafe header" error message
              return;
            }

            myXHR.setRequestHeader(headerKey, headerVal);
          });
        }
        myXHR.send(requestOptions.body);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('S3 XHRHandler error', e);
        reject(e);
      }
    });

    const raceOfPromises = [
      xhrPromise.then((response) => {
        const fetchHeaders = response.headers;
        const transformedHeaders: HeaderBag = {};

        fetchHeaders.forEach(header => {
          const name = header.substr(0, header.indexOf(':') + 1);
          const val =  header.substr(header.indexOf(':') + 1);
          if (name && val) {
            transformedHeaders[name] = val;
          }
        });

        const hasReadableStream = response.body !== undefined;

        // Return the response with buffered body
        if (!hasReadableStream) {
          return response.body.text().then(body => ({
            response: new HttpResponse({
              headers: transformedHeaders,
              statusCode: response.status,
              body,
            }),
          }));
        }
        // Return the response with streaming body
        return {
          response: new HttpResponse({
            headers: transformedHeaders,
            statusCode: response.status,
            body: response.body,
          }),
        };
      }),
      this.requestTimeoutFn(requestTimeoutInMs),
    ];
    if (abortSignal) {
      raceOfPromises.push(
        new Promise<never>((resolve, reject) => {
          abortSignal.onabort = () => {
            myXHR.abort();
          };
        })
      );
    }
    return Promise.race(raceOfPromises);
  }

  private requestTimeoutFn(timeoutInMs = 0): Promise<never> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (timeoutInMs) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const timeoutError = new Error(`Request did not complete within ${timeoutInMs} ms`);
          timeoutError.name = 'TimeoutError';
          reject(timeoutError);
        }, timeoutInMs);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not work with the libStorage upload. Did you ever try this with a multipart upload ?

Comment: With a slight tweak to the above code [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77417493/1129632) this worked for multi-part uploads.

Answer (score 5):

I have also faced the same issue that is i have to upgrade aws-sdk from v2 to v3 but file upload progress feature is missing in v3.The reason for that is in JS SDK v2 for S3 file upload they uses XHR for browser network requests, which has a good interface for progress tracking.
Whereas JS SDK v3 uses fetch for the same, which offers some other advantages but one downside is that it does not seem to support upload progress yet, and progress on that feature is extremely slow.

But now JS SDK v3 has a new package called @aws-sdk/xhr-http-handler which can be used in place of @aws-sdk/fetch-http-handler in order to get the fine grained file upload progress as we are getting in v2.

You can find out the code for that on the link https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/packages/xhr-http-handler

```
       import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
       import { XhrHttpHandler } from '@aws-sdk/xhr-http-handler';
       import { Upload } from '@aws-sdk/lib-storage';
        
         const s3Client = new S3Client({
          requestHandler: new XhrHttpHandler({}),
        }); 
        const upload = new Upload({
                        client:s3Client,
                        params: {
                           bucket,
                           key,
                         },
                     });
upload.on("httpUploadProgress", (progress) => {
  console.log(
    progress.loaded, // Bytes uploaded so far.
    progress.total // Total bytes. Divide these two for progress percentage.
  );
});
await upload.done();
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the [github issues](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/571) I've just found that `@aws-sdk/client-s3` don't support upload progress tracking, since it uses `fetchHttpHandler` under the covers. The recommended way is to use `@aws-sdk/lib-storage` which I have not tried yet, but looks promising!

Comment: see this has https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/b07e71986817d7781e12d9b687532c58d5ea6ba0/lib/storage/example-code/file-upload.ts example

Comment: This gives progress update every 5MB uploaded or so. Better than nothing  but not great

Answer (score 0):

[Jan's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66602781/1129632) worked for me with multi-part uploads, but one bugfix was required (working with v3.438.0 of @aws-sdk/client-s3), as the response headers of the PUT request were not being parsed correctly.

I changed

```
fetchHeaders.forEach((header) => {
  const name = header.substr(0, header.indexOf(':') + 1);
  const val = header.substr(header.indexOf(':') + 1);
  if (name && val) {
    transformedHeaders[name] = val;
  }
});
```

to

```
fetchHeaders.forEach((header) => {
  const name = header.indexOf(':') > -1 ? header.split(':')[0].trim() : null;
  const val = header.indexOf(':') > -1 ? header.split(':')[1].trim() : null;
  if (name && val) {
    transformedHeaders[name] = val;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's still not supported in the end of 2023, here's my function utilizing RxJS, XHR and signed URL to achieve it:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export function trackFileUpload(file: File, signedUrl: string): Observable<number> {
  return new Observable((observer) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Set up the request
    xhr.open('PUT', signedUrl, true);
    // set some custom headers
    xhr.setRequestHeader('key', 'value');

    // Set up listeners to track the progress and completion of the request
    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        const percentComplete = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
        // Emit the progress percentage
        observer.next(percentComplete);
      }
    };

    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        // Emit a success message upon successful upload
        observer.complete();
      } else {
        // Emit an error if the request fails
        observer.error(`Failed to upload. Server returned status: ${xhr.status}`);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = () => {
      // Emit an error in case of a network error
      observer.error('Failed to upload. Network error occurred.');
    };

    // Send the request with the file
    xhr.send(file);

    // teardown function
    return () => {
      if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        xhr.abort();
      }
    };
  });
}
```