# How can I show a progress indicator for uploading a file using Nuxt3 built-in $fetch (ohmyfetch)?

Tags: nuxt.js, fetch-api, nuxtjs3

Nuxt3 documentation [suggests](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/migration/component-options/#isomorphic-fetch) using its built-in `$fetch` method for making API calls. I'm trying to show the upload progress for a file uploader. I've done it with Axios before, but it does not work with the `$fetch` method. Here is my code which works with Axios:

```js
//...
const config = {
  onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
    progress.value = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)*100);
  }
}

$fetch('/portfolio/upload/', {method: 'POST', body: formdata, config});
//...
```

I've looked into the **ohmyfetch** documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/unjs/ohmyfetch), but I did not find anything. Any idea about how can I handle upload progress using the `$fetch` method?

Comment: I'm not even sure this can be done with Axios. For me, it was a fetch thing. Maybe create an issue on the repo.

Comment: @kissu there is already an open issue there https://github.com/unjs/ohmyfetch/issues/45

Answer (score 3):

Fetch or `ofetch` don't support uploading progress, right now this can be done only in browser with `XMLHttpRequest`, something like this:

```js
function upload (url, file) {
    const form = new FormData()
    form.append('file', file)

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('post', url, true)
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (ev) {
        // Upload progress here
        console.log(ev)
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            // Uploaded
            console.log('Uploaded')
        }
    }
    xhr.send(form)
}
```

You can find more about this here [Upload progress indicators for fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711724/upload-progress-indicators-for-fetch)

Comment: Pretty sure `XMLHttpRequest` is not needed and at least `fetch` support it.

Comment: @kissu No, it doesn't, https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api : `The fetch() method is relatively low-level API for fetching resources. It covers slightly more ground than XMLHttpRequest, although it is currently lacking when it comes to request progression (not response progression).`

Comment: What's the difference between [download progression](https://javascript.info/fetch-progress) and request progression?

Comment: @kissu request progression is the same as upload progression, when you upload large files. Even in the link you added there is text: `Please note: there’s currently no way for fetch to track upload progress. For that purpose, please use XMLHttpRequest, we’ll cover it later.`

Comment: @kissu it's download progress vs upload progress