# Jquery , IF page is loading for more than 15 sec and is still not complete

Tags: jquery, load

IT is poosible to do this in jquery ..
FOr example if users that access my website and their speed is slow i want on them to appear an message where to write click here for a mini theme .. and this message to appear only if the page is loading in 15 second or more

Answer (score 0):

In the below link You can Test the speed of Internet.

You can check with Fiddle also

Check :[How to detect internet speed in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)

After you found the connection is low then show the popup.

Comment: Not only accepted answer .Check the third answer with working fiddle .