# How to use Modernizr for user bandwidth detection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, modernizr

I currently building full background website with video. I make background image sliding, just in case if user internet just run slow. I want to achieve it with modernizr, or any way if possible.

my concept : 
if user bandwidth is fast --> using video,
 
if user bandwidth is slow --> using image sliding.

Here my code.

```
<div id="con">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
    <div id="imgslide" style="display: none;">
        <img src="img1.png"/>
        <img src="img2.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate for your help.

Comment: I've just done this fairly successfully for a project and am in the process of writing a blog post about it – I'll drop the link here when it's finished.

Comment: Great I'll wait for it :D

Comment: @StuCox did you write that post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/network/connection.js), a lowbandwidth test was available with Modernizr.

As mentioned in the comments, the detection was based only on the device information.

Unluckily it has been removed due to [this issue](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1051).

Anyway, [other mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript) have been shown to be effective, and you can also have a look at libraries like [jsbandwidth](https://code.google.com/p/jsbandwidth/),  [foresight](https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js/) or [boomerang](http://lognormal.github.io/boomerang/doc/).