# How to detect Bandwidth/ Net speed using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to detect Bandwidth/ Net speed using javascript ?

Link below is  not exactly works.

[How to detect internet speed in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)

Can any one cordinate about this issue.

Thanks
Anil Neel

Answer (score 0):

In one of my current projects, I came across a scenario to play a video based on the users downloading bandwidth. The detection should be done with javascript. There is a technique, to load an image of known size and calculating the bandwidth on basis of time taken to load that image. Though this technique is not 100% reliable, this will give an approximate estimate of bandwidth.

Example can be found here: http://blog.weareon.net/bandwidth-detection-with-javascript/

Comment: Thanks SekDinesh, Is there any other solution ?

Comment: What is this? Link you have shared is a spam link, not working?