# Youtube API: is there a way to know the internet connection speed of user using api

Tags: youtube-api

1)is there a way to find out the user's net speed using youtube api
2)is there a way to find out how much buffering is left out or is complete or not using youtube api.

if not supported by youtube api, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't think the API provides this. There's an example here: [How to detect internet speed in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)

2) Check the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=de) for the JavaScript Player API:

> **player.getVideoLoadedFraction():Float**
>
> Returns a number between 0 and 1 that specifies the percentage of the
>   video that the player shows as buffered. This method returns a more
>   reliable number than the now-deprecated getVideoBytesLoaded and
>   getVideoBytesTotal methods.