# Youtube Api Auto Change Video Quality

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Is there any way to automatically detect if a user can handle a higher video resolution?

Right now I'm setting the user playback quality to 'default' in onPlayerReady. I can check if there is a higher resolution available using getAvailableQualityLevels()-1 in the onPlayerStateChange but I don't know if changing the resolution will cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no direct way to do it. But as this [previous post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397840/youtube-api-is-there-a-way-to-know-the-internet-connection-speed-of-user-using), you can do it using two ways:

1. Use the javascript method in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript).
2. Use the buffered video size as a quality estimate

Over the suggested methods my suggestion is to make it a slow process more like a [kalman filter](http://interactive-matter.eu/blog/2009/12/18/filtering-sensor-data-with-a-kalman-filter/). Hope it helps.