# How does youtube determine default video quality

Tags: php, youtube, video-streaming

I have noticed that youtube and dailymotion have a mechanism in place to be able to "choose" a video quality for you based on your internet connection.For e.g since i have a 1 mbps internet connection , video load at 360p by default.For those with higher internet connection video load at 480p/720p/1024

How does youtube determine which internet connection i have ?

Implementing such a feature definitely reduce bandwidth for the host and enhance the user experience.

I would love a php based solution so that i can try to implement this on my site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Determining the available bandwidth for a web based video player is done *client side*. If the client (ie the player) **thinks** it has not sufficient bandwidth to maintain playback at the current bitrate without buffering it requests a lower bitrate rendition to the server (and the other way around). This is a well known mechanism of adaptive bitrate streaming - client bandwidth is checked at startup and at fixed intervals and based on those results the player is able to react to maintain decent playback. PHP being a sever side scripting language cannot be used for this part of the process.

For Youtube flash based player I guess they use their own flavor of action script bandwidth detection. If you use FMS there is a native way to achieve [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d56e-7ffaDev.html). Otherwise you need to code it yourself. [Here](http://www.codingcolor.com/as3/bandwidth-detection-with-as3/) is to give you an idea on how to implement this.

For JavaScript you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript). Based on available internet connection speed you can then make your player to take a decision.

You could consider looking at MPEG DASH that has a [JS lib](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki) with bandwidth detection built in it.