# How to detect internet speed and service provider in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to design a simple HTML page to show Internet service provider and speed of Internet. How can I do it in JavaScript or jquery .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript

Comment: Javascript code runs on client side. If you want a reliable way to determine speed and service provider, I would suggest you look into a server side solution.

Comment: nope, that can't be done on the client side

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/21x7vo14/