# How to find out the internet connection speed of user using JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find out the internet connection speed of user's PC using JavaScript or jquery.

Could someone please look into this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript

Comment: What have you tried? You can simply check the time between the start and response of an Ajax request, but that is the response speed of that server.

Comment: @ Paul:  refered code is working but i dont thik it's resulting to required aspect, when i am hitting this code with one image at localhost, its giving different result every time like this::::Your connection speed is: 4234.63 Mbps, Your connection speed is: 1022.63 Mbps, Your connection speed is: 5005.64 Mbps

Comment: Hey Paul: can you please help me out to understand why this is giving that much speed which is not correct? Thanks for you time, buddy ! :)

Comment: its a bit urgent if somebody can help me out here, that will be great, please help me out to understand, speed is too bigger like 100 mbps, 150 mbps but i actually tried online that actual downloading speed is 2.5 ro 3 mbps.

Comment: This is too brief for questions here, voting to delete.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do that to estimated download bandwidth in megabytes per second of the current connection.

```
// Some browsers use prefixes so let's cope with them first
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;

// Check for browser support
if (!!connection) {
  // Get the connection type
  var type = connection.type;

  // Get the connection speed in megabits per second (Mbps)
  var speed = connection.downlinkMax || connection.bandwidth;
}
```

Comment: connection.bandwidth is javascript property or do i need to add something to get this working.

Comment: i have tried this code but its not working, connection is being fired at undefined.
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;

  alert("connection="+navigator.connection);
  // Check for browser support
  if (!!connection) {
    // Get the connection type
    var type = connection.type;
    alert("type="+type);
    // Get the connection speed in megabits per second (Mbps)
    var speed = connection.downlinkMax || connection.bandwidth;
     alert("speed="+speed);

  }

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/connection#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I have referred the link, but that is not supported with all browsers..

Comment: `downlinkMax` is indeed in megabits per second, but `bandwidth` is in megabytes per second. Then again, `bandwidth` was never supported by any stable browser, and `downlinkMax` is not supported yet by any stable browser...

Comment: Currently the only major browser that supports this is [Chrome on Android](http://caniuse.com/#feat=netinfo). For now it's probably better to use the method outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript).

Comment: On newest version on chrome, connection is undefined