# Check connection speed and depending on that speed, decide what website to send to the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Check connection speed and depending on that speed decide, what website to send to the user ?!

For example, if have mobile internet something like 5 kbps or an another low internet connection.

Slow connection(e.g. less 500 kilo Bytes ,just send plain html faster than that send big web site.

Any modules that do that work for me or forther informations, would be very nice :)

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript ?

Comment: 'Speed' is a very deceptive word in network performance. Do you mean latency (i.e. two-way delay) or bandwidth (i.e. width of the pipe)? Or a combination of both? Answering this will dictate the applicable solutions.