# test for internet connection strength

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on inventory management system (offline). It requires synchronizing offline database with online database whenever there is internet connection. My question is how do I test for the strength of my client connection. If the connection is fast i perform the synchronization otherwise try again later. I will be glad if possibly through javascript or jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5529841/4161269

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect internet speed in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)