# How to Find Internet Speed in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

how to find internet speed in ionic application and which is the best way to do it ? Is there any plugin to find internet Speed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a **Network Information** plugin for cordova/ionic that might help determine the network, and then you can go from there.  Install it like this:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

Use it like:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.Connection) {
        if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

The available options are:
Connection.UNKNOWN
Connection.ETHERNET
Connection.WIFI
Connection.CELL_2G
Connection.CELL_3G
Connection.CELL_4G
Connection.NONE

Here's a [blog post](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/check-network-connection-with-ionicframework/) that might help.

Comment: Thank You for your reply mrust , it will be the solution for my question , I will work on it and let u know if any issues.   Thank U .

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript pure you can have an approximate numerical result, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript?lq=1)

I think this is best way to do it