# How can I test any given CDN performance through Javascript? Is there any tools for that purpose?

Tags: javascript, networking, cdn

I would like to test the **content download speed**, how fast was the **first byte** transferred, the **size** of the content being requested, **full-load** time, **document complete** time and other in-depth characteristics that could really be tested.

What can I think of is sending an AJAX request to download the given resource from the CDN and the time the AJAX request is completed will be the content downloaded time. I am not really sure how accurate would the result be.

What about the other characteristics?

Are there any tools/libraries built for this? Accuracy is vast importance for the tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect internet speed in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)

Comment: use `Date.now()` before the request to gt the start time. use the same to get timestamp when request is returned. subtract. real rocket science stuff.

Comment: also, there are tools for this. google before you ask: https://tools.pingdom.com/

Comment: @user3608792 it is not a duplicate of "How to detect internet speed in Javascript", since I'm not interested in my speed rather than the performance by the CDN I'm testing. @I wrestled a bear once Thanks, I guess I did not research enough.

Comment: How else would you define "performance?" You could download an image with a know size from the CDN and check the load time. The principle is the same.