# What is it that google maps uses to get our precise location of the client? can we do it using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to get following details of the clients visiting my website.
Their pretty precise location, i.e. part of town they're living in to analyze data. 
and their static IP address (if possible). 
connection speed (can they receive data updates on real time basis). Could you please find solution on this ?

Answer (score 3):

[Geolocation service](http://Geolocation%20service). An API provided by the browser (not jQuery!)

This can only get you their location, static IP address you can get via the server, connection speed is [calculable on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript), but not very accurately. There are no standard client side APIs to get you IP address or connection speed.