# How to track internet speed data using google Tag Manger?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track internet speed(2G, 3G, 4G, wifi, etc) of the user using Google tag manager. Let me know the step for this

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that with Google Tag Manager by default.

It is **a definitely bad practice** for your website visitors, but if you want to know their speed in MB/s (it is not very precise), you can do that following:

1) Create API endpoint on your website which will respond exact 1MB of any data.

2) Write JS code, which will measure how much time they spent on downloading 1MB data

```
var start_time = new Date().getTime();

jQuery.get('your-url'+ '?timestamp=' + new Date.getTime().toString(), 
    function(data, status, xhr) {
        var request_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
        var mbs= 1/(request_time/1000.0); //this variable will have speed in MBS
        dataLayer.push({'speed': mbs});
    }
);
```

3) Read this dataLayer in GTM

Again, it is a bad practice and it is not very precise

Answer (score 0):

Victors answer, as unprecise as the results may be, is probably the easiest way (and for most use cases having a few buckets for the users should be okay). It will also work in any halfway modern browser. An implementation that does not rely on jQuery can be [found in this very old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript) (you'd need to adapt this to push the value to the datalayer).

For completeness sake:

- There are also [dedicated services](http://speedof.me/api.html) to measure connection speed
  (I'm not affiliated, I just googled it).
- If you are feeling adventurous you might want to explore the
  [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation), which is currently mostly useless due
  to almost non-existent browser support, but might be implemented at
  some point in the future (the [downlinkMax property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/downlinkMax) should give you the maximal possible speed for downloads)