# How to calculate Internet speed in angular 2/4

Tags: angular

Hi i want to calculate internet download /upload sped and ping time using Angular 2/4. is it possible to do so in angular. i am new in angular so i have not too much idea in angular. If any one know then please suggest me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect internet speed in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)

Comment: please can you explain that how to implement it in angular...?