# How to detect user's connection speed using angular 2 and set quality to twilio video call

Tags: javascript, angular, twilio, video-conferencing, twilio-video

I am trying to set default video quality for video like this (from the example) :

```
createLocalTracks({
  audio: true,
  video: { width: 640 }
}).then(localTracks => {
  return connect('$TOKEN', {
    name: 'my-room-name',
    tracks: localTracks
  });
}).then(room => {
  console.log('Connected to Room:', room.name);
});
```

instead of width : 640 i want to set dynamic resolution for the video base on user's internet connection. How can I do that?

Comment: May be you can use the idea from this question: [how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)

Comment: Peraps you can load a file or page of a known size, this won't be totally correct, but will give you some kind of estimate. You a callback when the file was loaded and check how much time elapsed

Comment: @anand were you able to get a solution to this?
Were you able to change video resolution based on the network conditions?
Not just during initialization but also once the call has started?

Comment: @UdayReddy not yet