# How can we detect network speed by javascript when WiFi connected but internet speed is very low/limited?

Tags: javascript

I have tried

```js
window.navigator.connection.downlink
```

but I didn't get proper result. I don't want to use any packages from `fast`, `speedtest`, `ookla` cause they required CORS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect internet speed in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript) question. It's an onld question but it can help you to go in the right direction.