# Auto-Adjust quality based on user connection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to do a test and misure the connection quality of the user on a web page.
How can I check their connection and use the result for let them recorder video based on their connection?

I can’t let them recorder one video of 1:30 min on fullHD and then take 5 minutes for upload.

Thank you all

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please make some research before asking a question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript

Comment: I’m glad that you answer me, but I would like to know the upload speed. I’ve already read this post and test it, but i’ve noticed that it wasn’t what i’m looking for.

Comment: Here a solution not from me : http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/z8KXd/

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate that