# Testing network speed at all times without downloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `react` web app and a `react-native` mobile app. I want to add a "Slow Internet Connection Detected!" warning whenever the users network connection is slow.
Checking the speed at one instant is fine (By checking the time taken to complete a download of known size).
I want to detect the internet speed of the user at all times such that whenever the speed drops the warning comes on.
I am not able to find a way to do that. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: @Nikhil Probably something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript