# Measuring internet speed in a web application

Tags: javascript

We have a comprehensive web application using Vonage Video API (TokBox) extensively. Task in hand is to monitor and log clients network bandwidth/internet speed, which is a browser application.

After a lot of research I have 2 solutions

- window.navigator.connection - we support Safari but safari doesn't support this
- download a image from server and measuring the time taken. It will work with Safari too but will be a overhead, especially when we want to log client internet speed every 2 minutes.

Is there any way to measure internet speed in a web application using low level component, like a network adapter?

Comment: A WebSocket is what you probably need, no?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv can you please elaborate a bit? Won't opening a websocket to test internet speed will be a overhead? or I am missing out on anything?

Comment: Well, how can you measure internet speed without transferring data? A WebSocket will have the smallest overhead because it's not dependant on DOM in any way and you can do it in a service worker too. Same for bandwidth, only way to measure that is to keep transferring data in large volume until you hit a limit.

Comment: Check this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript).