# How to check Network Connection quality between server and client in ASP.NET web application

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, connection, pagespeed-insights

in our website application, Our clients complaining about web site speed, they say it's keep waiting aroud 20secs, but when we check We see around 2 secs which is acceptable. We are guessing there is speed fluctuation, Maybe because of client's bad internet connection or server itself.

Could you please suggest me a way to detect this programmatically?

Let's just say, there will be a html button at that moment, user click's that to check connection quality between server and client, ping duration, speed etc. I wanna say, you have bad internet connection or there is a problem with server itself.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript) perhaps help you