# How Get Client Upload Speed

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

So i am integrating zoom websdk in my wordpress website. My requirement is, i want to show alert message to user when their upload speed get decreases to some particular speed(let's say 2mbps). I have been looking for some libraries but not able to get any library that gives me upload speed of the client. can anyone please help me out with the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript

Comment: Hi @WM-SH-PD-TV-FC , i've already checked this one,
this solutions gives download speed and it is not accurate as well.

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX,
yes something that runs with some particular interval like 5 mins or 10 mins

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, sorry not able to understand what you are saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233826/discussion-between-dipak-sumesara-and-jaromanda-x).