# React: Detect poor connection or cheap device

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a service that displays videos, but I want to change the video quality before downloading it. I need to detect either the device or the network connection, to see if they're poor or not. What is the most effective way of doing it?

Comment: [Detect internet speed (inaccurate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, it's not a super straightforward path - because what you are talking about is a video streaming service. To do it properly, as in developing your own solution, requires sophisticated engineering and is not something that I would suggest for a single developer to do.

But, what you do want is a video streaming CDN - and I suggest you look into CDNs as a whole if you're going to deliver rich media to end users - it will likely make it easier, faster and cheaper than whatever solution you can implement yourself.

A good alternative is CloudFlare - probably the gold standard of CDNs - but there are many out there. [Video Streaming CDN Docs](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/video/what-is-video-cdn/)

This solution automatically detects network capabilities of your client - and transcodes and delivers media in a way that fits. You can read more in the docs.

Good luck.