# Test internet connection speed or page load time

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to check the users connection speed to display a message when the internet connection is bad. I found some solutions on SO downloading an image and measuring the time it takes.

For example here: [How to detect internet speed in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529718/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-javascript/5529841?noredirect=1#comment43005081_5529841)

This is what I tried:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const startTime = new Date().getTime();
    const url = `xxx?killCache=${startTime.toString()}`;
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = () => {
        const duration = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        console.log(duration)
        if(duration > 750){
            setHasSlowConnection(true)
        }
    }
    image.src = url;
}, []);
```

However this seems to be really inaccurate especially when using small images. I tried with a file of 25.5 kb. The calculated duration without throttling (600+ MBit/s) is about 200ms. For throttled connection (Using Chromes throttling, fast 3G) it is about 850m. It is only 4 times slower while the connection is actually several hundred times worse. Is it possible that increased image size will improve accuracy? In this case however you don't want to download big sized files for users already having a bad connection. What could be a suitable file size here?

An alternative would be to measure the time i took to render the whole page but I don't know how to achieve that. Any help on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: Packet loss, latency, and dodgy DNS (DNS timeouts, ISPs lying about NXDOMAIN, etc) are far bigger causes of poor UX than connection speed. For example, wherever you're on 100mbps or 1Gbps (i.e. a 10x speed improvement) isn't going to make BankOfAmerica's online banking any less awful.

Comment: @Dai This might be correct but doesn't really answer my question, does it?

Comment: It doesn't, but I'm trying to convince you that you're wasting your time barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Also, don't use `new Date()` in JS for performance-timing, use the purpose-built Performance API instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance

Comment: @Dai Not my decision though.