Is it possible to serve a different version of a website to people with slow connection?
I'd like users of my website to have a reasonable experience even on slow connection and I think a reasonable way to achieve that is to serve them a "minimal" version of the website with as little JS/CSS as possible.
However, I have no idea whether it is possible to detect the connection speed and serve a different version based on that? How would one achieve this?
(On a similar note, it would be nice to not serve large files like videos to users who are using mobile data - is there some way to detect whether the user is using WiFi or mobile data? Or some API by which they can tell you that they don't want to download large things?)

besides frontend optimization techniques (such as reducing http requests, minifying, caching, lazy loading and etc.) there are other ways to achieve a faster experience. you can detect network speed (if it's 2g, 3g, or 4g+) and made your code behave according to the slow network so that visitors can have the desired experience. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API this api is to achieve it however it works on Chromium-based browsers.

This post should be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5529718/18595321

You can use NetworkInformation to detect the connection type, but it's not fully supported
